# How can I make the scaffold for this login screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've tried a lot of different things to make widgets line up but I'm quite new to flutter and can't make scaffolds with ease. I want my screen to look like this. [image] I am really struggling with just aligning things relative to others, like putting the 2 textviews under the icon, and aligning things relative to the page. My flutter code is also terrible so there's probably no point in me putting it. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This was greatly aided by William Terrill and Josteve Adekanbi's answer

Here's my final code after compiling things from various places:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset('assets/ic_launcher_round.png', fit: BoxFit.contain, width: 100, height: 100),
                      Builder(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return
                          IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(MyFlutterApp.settings),
                              color: Colors.black,
                              onPressed: () {
                                  navigateToSettings(context);
                              },
                          );
                      }
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Highlands Latin School",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Color(0xFF012B5C), fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Canvas Grades",
                    style: TextStyle(color:  Color(0xFF827250), fontSize: 18,),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextField(
                        controller: myController1,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Email",
                            border: OutlineInputBorder()
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Visibility(
                        visible: _isVisible,
                        child: TextField(
                          obscureText: _obscureText,
                          controller: myController2,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: "Password",
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(_obscureText ? Icons.visibility_off: Icons.visibility),
                                onPressed: (){
                                  setState(() {
                                    _obscureText = !_obscureText;
                                  });
                                },
                              )
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Visibility(
                                visible: _isVisible,
                                maintainSize: true,
                                maintainState: true,
                                maintainAnimation: true,
                                child: Checkbox(
                                  value: _isChecked,
                                  activeColor: Color(0xFF827250),
                                  onChanged: (bool value){
                                    setState(() {
                                      _isChecked = value;
                                      if (_isChecked) {
                                        prefs.setString("email", Email);
                                        prefs.setString("pass", Password);
                                        prefs.setBool("remember", true);
                                      } else {
                                        prefs.setString("email", "");
                                        prefs.setString("pass", "");
                                        prefs.setBool("remember", false);
                                      }
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                              Visibility(
                                  maintainSize: true,
                                  maintainState: true,
                                  maintainAnimation: true,
                                  visible: _isVisible,
                                  child: Text(
                                  "SAVE LOGIN?", style: TextStyle(color:  Color(0xFF827250)),
                              )
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          GestureDetector(
                            onTap: (){
                              setState(() {
                                if (_forgotPassText == "FORGOT PASSWORD?") {
                                  _forgotPassText = "Back to Login";
                                  _loginText = "Request Password";
                                  _isVisible = false;
                                } else {
                                  _forgotPassText = "FORGOT PASSWORD?";
                                  _loginText = "Login";
                                  _isVisible = true;
                                }});
                            },
                            child: Text(_forgotPassText, style: TextStyle(color:  Color(0xFF827250))
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                ProgressButton(
                  child: Text(
                    _loginText,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18
                    ),
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: Color(0xFF012B5C),
                  buttonState: _buttonState,
                  progressColor: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () async {
                          //custom login method, edit _buttonState to make the button become spinner
                    }
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  child: Text(error, style: TextStyle(color: _errorColor),
                  ),
                ),
                ]
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I added Visibilities and variables to setStates to change colors, texts, etc on the fly in my various methods. Also, I put the text at the very bottom under the button that wasn't shown in the original picture.

Answer (score 4):

Check this out

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  bool _obscureText = true;
  bool _isChecked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: 85,
                        height: 85,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blue[900],
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.settings,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        size: 40,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Highlands Latin School",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.blue[900]),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Canvas Grades",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700], fontSize: 18),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Email",
                            border: OutlineInputBorder()
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      TextField(
                        obscureText: _obscureText,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Password",
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          suffixIcon: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(_obscureText ? Icons.visibility_off: Icons.visibility),
                            onPressed: (){
                              setState(() {
                                _obscureText = !_obscureText;
                              });
                            },
                          )
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Checkbox(
                                value: _isChecked,
                                onChanged: (value){
                                  setState(() {
                                    _isChecked = !_isChecked;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "SAVE LOGIN?"
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 30,
                            width: 1,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                          GestureDetector(
                            onTap: (){},
                            child: Text(
                              "FORGOT PASSWORD?"
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text(
                    "Login",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18
                    ),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  color: Colors.blue[900],
                  onPressed: (){

                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Ouput:**
[image]

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hey! I like this. I saw you did the eye on the password... I didn't even know suffixIcon even existed for TextField->InputDecoration. I'm upvoting yours because we're the only two people on the planet that did this design.

Comment: Thanks for posting this Josteve! I used some elements of your code and William's as well, and I changed some icons/colors/and the button around (the button in my Android app was a custom library that made it morph into a spinner when pressed).

Answer (score 3):

I did one here.  You can check out the code in this dart: 
https://dartpad.dev/ab2b2531e943d0006164711a5e345be7
and an image:
[image]

I tried to make it as responsive as possible, and I put it in a container to simulate a phone device.  You can adjust the width and height directly in the code to see it on different phone sizes. (However, in the final version, you'd want to use a MediaQuery to get that data)

It needs to be refactored, but I wanted to keep it in one file in order to put it in dartpad.

I know it's a little overwhelming at first to do these layouts, so it's always better to go in steps.  This is basically how I approach most layouts:
1. define smaller areas: I defined these in my code and put them in a Stack:
 the cog, the crest, the title block, the input block, and the login button
2. Figure out what widgets you can use for each one... and be on the lookout for rows inside of columns, and columns inside of rows.
3. position the widgets.  This can either be by exact positioning in a Stack, which I used in this code, or by putting in padding around widgets

Here's the full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

var width = 350.0; // <-- play with these numbers
var height = 700.0; // <-- to see it on different sized devices

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool trueFalse;
  initState() {
    trueFalse = true;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//  width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;  <-- this is where you would
//  height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height; <-- get the real width/height
    print(trueFalse);
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        width: width,
        height: height,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(25.0),
              child: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.grey[850])),
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                // THIS IS THE SETTINGS COG
                right: width * 0.02,
                top: height * 0.03,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.settings,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  size: width * 0.1,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                  // THIS IS THE CREST AND BACKGROUND
                  left: width * 0.05,
                  top: height * 0.05,
                  child: Container(
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: Image(
                            image: NetworkImage(
                                'http://highlandslatin.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Monogram-white.png'))),
                    width: width * 0.20,
                    height: width * 0.20,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                    ),
                  )),
              Positioned(
                // THIS IS THE HIGHLANDS UPPER TEXT
                left: width * 0.05,
                top: height * 0.17,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text("Highlands Latin School",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    Container(height: 8),
                    Text("Canvas Grades",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                  // THIS IS THE LOGIN AREA
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width * 0.05),
                        child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                labelText: 'Email'))),
                    Container(height: 10),
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width * 0.05),
                        child: TextField(
                            obscureText: true,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                labelText: 'Password'))),
                    Container(height: 10),
                    Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                              padding:
                                  EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(width * 0.01, 0, 0, 0),
                              child: Container(
                                child: Row(children: [
                                  Checkbox(
                                    value: trueFalse,
                                    onChanged: (bool value) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        trueFalse =
                                            value; // trueFalse?false:true;
                                      });
                                      print("check mark changed");
                                      print(value);
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(1, 0, 0, 0),
                                      child: Text("Save Login?")),
                                ]),
                              )),
                          Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: width * 0.05),
                              child: Text("Forgot Password")),
                        ])
                  ]),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, width * 0.05),
                  child: Container(
                    width: width - 2 * width * 0.05,
                    child: FlatButton(
                      color: Colors.grey[850],
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 11.0, horizontal: width * 0.05),
                      splashColor: Colors.blue,
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("button pressed");
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        "Login",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it did, and I wish I could accept two answers... but I can't. I combined some of yours and some of Josteve's answer - thanks for helping me out! After looking through these the Scaffolds make a lot more sense.